# Lightweight userspace sandboxing of filesystem

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, namespace

I would like to trick a non-malicious process to think that it is writing to directory `$HOME/abc/def/` while it writes in fact to `$HOME/xyz/def` (the former path is hardcoded and it does not work for my for various reasons). The `$HOME/abc/def/` directory should not exists at all. I thought about using user namespace + filesystem name-space to mount a aufs filesystem over it but I failed (the mount finished stating insufficient privileges).

Is it possible to do using user + filesystem namespaces? If not is there any risk creating suid program that creates such filesystem namespace for single program (the setup is currently low-security but I prefer to be security concious)? Or maybe there is existing solution to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Will using a symbolic link not suffice? Example:

```
[root@talara ~]# ls -la /tmp/home/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul  5 16:01 .
drwxrwxrwt. 9 root root 4096 Jul  5 16:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul  5 16:01 123
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   13 Jul  5 16:01 321 -> /tmp/home/123
[root@talara ~]# touch /tmp/home/321/ACTIVITY_TEST
[root@talara ~]# ls -la /tmp/home/123/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  5 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  5 16:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul  5 16:02 ACTIVITY_TEST
[root@talara ~]#
```

This should suffice for tricking a hard coded script or program.

Comment: To some extend. One of the reason is that, for me, those files shouldn't be there and should not appear during `ls`, opening directory by file manager etc.

Comment: Ahh. Invisible folder.. Lets call this idea last ditch effort ;)